# Conversion of time from one timezone to other in groovy

Tags: groovy, timezone, soapui

I am trying to convert time from one timezone to others.

Initially, I have the time and its timezone. I want to convert it to other timezone.
e.g : 
Timezone : GMT Standard Time
StartDateTime : 2020-01-15T08:30:00.000Z

Now I want to convert it to IST timezone

Code :

```
def oldTimezone = context.expand('${#Project#Timezone}')
def SDT = context.expand('${#Project#StartDateTime}') 
startDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(SDT)
log.info 'time : ' + startDate 
def dateformat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
dateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(oldTimezone));
def currentTimeinUTC = dateformat.format(startDate);
log.info 'time set in first timezone : ' + currentTimeinUTC
```

Output

```
Wed Jan 15 14:43:32 IST 2020:INFO:time : Wed Jan 15 08:30:00 IST 2020
Wed Jan 15 14:56:16 IST 2020:INFO:time set in first timezone : 2020-01-15T03:00:00.000Z
```

If this will return me the output '2020-01-15T08:30:00.000Z' then I will convert it to IST with the same exact way. But the problem it understands that the original time is in IST and converts it to UTC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Time Conversion based on the TimeZone Java/Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084820/date-time-conversion-based-on-the-timezone-java-groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the old date classes, they make everything hard...

To parse that UTC time, and convert it to a IST time is as simple as:

```
import java.time.*

def parsedUTCTime = ZonedDateTime.parse('2020-01-15T08:30:00.000Z')

def istTime = parsedUTCTime.withZoneSameInstant(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST").toZoneId())
```

Comment: It would be better to use `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`.  No need to use the old `TimeZone` class, and short IDs should generally be avoided due to their ambiguity.

Comment: If I am not wrong this will assume that the original timezone is always UTC. Then you can choose any other timezone to convert. In my case, the given timezone is not fixed as UTC. It can be anything. e.g : I have to convert time from CST to IST.

Comment: If it ends with a z, it's UTC, no?